# Get data from binance api and save to ClickHouse DB

Tags: python, database, pandas

I did the following

1. Created DB and table in prepate_table function
2. Extracted data from binance in GetHistoricalData function
3. Saved the data to DB

My code works fine but I want to optimize my code and remove redundant steps

**My solution**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import time
import clickhouse_driver
import datetime

from binance.client import Client


# Binance test_key https://testnet.binance.vision/key/generate
API_KEY = "--"
API_SECRET = "--"


def GetHistoricalData(
    timedelta_days=10,
    ticker="BTCUSDT",
    kline_interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR
    ):
    # Calculate the timestamps for the binance api function
    untilThisDate = datetime.datetime.now()
    sinceThisDate = untilThisDate - datetime.timedelta(days=timedelta_days)

    client = Client(API_KEY, API_SECRET) 
    client.API_URL = 'https://testnet.binance.vision/api'
    candle = client.get_historical_klines(ticker, kline_interval, str(sinceThisDate), str(untilThisDate))

    # Create a dataframe to label all the columns returned by binance so we work with them later.
    df = pd.DataFrame(candle, columns=['dateTime', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'closeTime', 'quoteAssetVolume', 'numberOfTrades', 'takerBuyBaseVol', 'takerBuyQuoteVol', 'ignore'])
    # as timestamp is returned in ms, let us convert this back to proper timestamps.
    df.dateTime = pd.to_datetime(df.dateTime, unit='ms').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")
    df.set_index('dateTime', inplace=True)

    # Get rid of columns we do not need
    df = df.drop(['quoteAssetVolume', 'numberOfTrades', 'takerBuyBaseVol','takerBuyQuoteVol', 'ignore'], axis=1)

    return df


def prepare_table():
    client = clickhouse_driver.Client.from_url(f'clickhouse://default:{os.getenv("CLICK_PASSWORD")}@localhost:9000/crypto_exchange')
    
    # field names from binance API
    client.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS historical_data_binance
(
    dateTime DateTime,
    closeTime Int64,
    open Float64,
    high Float64,
    low Float64,
    close Float64,
    volume Float64,
    kline_type String,
    ticker String
) ENGINE = Memory
''')
    return client



def insert_data(client, insert_data, db_name="crypto_exchange", table_name="historical_data_binance"):
    """
    insert_data = {
        "dateTime": dateTime, 
        "closeTime": closeTime, 
        "open": open,
        "high": hign,
        "low": low,
        "close": close,
        "volume": volume,
        "kline_type": kline_type,
        "ticker": ticker
    }
    """
    columns = ', '.join(insert_data.keys())
    query = 'insert into {}.{} ({}) values'.format(db_name, table_name, columns)
    
    data = []
    data.append(insert_data)
    client.execute(query, data)


client_db = prepare_table()
hist_data = GetHistoricalData(kline_interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR, ticker="BTCUSDT",)
for row in hist_data.iterrows():
    data = row[1].to_dict()
    data["dateTime"] =  datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d %X")
    data["closeTime"] = int(data["closeTime"])
    data["open"] = float(data["open"])
    data["high"] = float(data["high"])
    data["low"] = float(data["low"])
    data["close"] = float(data["close"])
    data["volume"] = float(data["volume"])
    data["kline_type"] = Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR
    data["ticker"] = "BTCUSDT"
    insert_data(client_db, data)
```

What can be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- By PEP8, `GetHistoricalData` should be `get_historical_data`; likewise for your local variables like `until_this_date`
- Introduce PEP484 type hints, for instance `timedelta_days: Real` (if it's allowed to be floating-point) or `int` otherwise
- You should not be redefining `'https://testnet.binance.vision/api'`; that's already defined as `BaseClient.API_TESTNET_URL` - see [the documentation](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/binance/client.html). This also suggests that you should be using `testnet=True` upon construction.
- This date conversion:

```
    df.dateTime = pd.to_datetime(df.dateTime, unit='ms').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")
```

is only half good idea. Datetime data should be stored in machine format instead of rendered user presentation data, so keep the `to_datetime` and drop the `strftime`.

- When you call `df.drop`, pass `inplace=True` since you overwrite `df` anyway.
- Your use of `iterrows` broken down into individual ClickHouse insert statements is going to be slow. [ClickHouse supports multi-row `values()` syntax.](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/insert-into/) Try making insertion batches that use this syntax to reduce the total number of inserts that you perform.